# NoMethodError in .js.erb

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to write unobtrusive javascript, and I have in my view:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "trend" %>
```

and in my trend.js.erb there is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    <% @testsss.each do |t|%>

        $('#<%= "t-"+t.id.to_s %>').click(function(event){
            //alert("sometext");
            $.ajax({type: "GET", url: "/returngraph?test=<%= t.id.to_s %>", dataType: "html",success: 
            function(data){ $("#chart").html(data)} });

        }); 

    <% end %>


});
```

But I got NoMethodError...
what I am doing wrong? @testsss is set of objects and same @testsss.each works in trend.html.erb from where I call javascript_include_tag "trend"

thank you

edit:

here is actual error:

```
NoMethodError in Statisticall#trend

Showing /xxxx/app/views/statisticall/trend.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
  (in /xxxx/app/assets/javascripts/trend.js.erb)
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= javascript_include_tag "trend" %>
2: <div id="hhead">
```

I have controller Statisticall and action trend

Comment: Can you add the actual error (which will tell you which method it tried to call)?

Comment: I solved this that I moved all from .js.erb to .html.erb and add it in <script></script> and like this it works...but that is not the ruby way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing @testsss is defined in a controller.

The asset pipeline is not compiled or ever touched by action controller so... you cannot have instance variables you assign in your controllers in the pipeline.

Work arounds include @testsss.to_json  and including that as a JS variable in your view

something like

```
#app/views/some/view.html.erb
<script type='text/javascript'>
 window.testsss = <%= @testsss.tojson %>
</script>
```

then in your javascript do something like this using underscore.js

```
  _(testsss).each(function(t){
    $('#t-'+ t.id).click(function(event){
         //alert("sometext");
         $.ajax({type: "GET", url: "/returngraph?test=" + t.id, dataType: "html",success: 
         function(data){ $("#chart").html(data)} });
     }); 
  });
```

or you can render that js inside a view rather than the asset pipeline

```
#app/views/some/view.html.erb
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    <% @testsss.each do |t|%>
      $('#<%= "t-"+t.id.to_s %>').click(function(event){
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "/returngraph?test=<%= t.id.to_s %>",
          dataType: "html",
          success: function(data){ $("#chart").html(data)}
        });
      }); 
    <% end %>
  });
</script>
```

Doing it this way gives you the advantage of having instance variables assigned in action controller in your js but the disadvantage of longer loading of your main page.

I perfer the first approach but that's up to you?